# Nvidia CUDA runtime error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have a Nvidia GT630 graphics card with driver version 384.90 on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the CUDA 9 toolkit successfully. The deviceQuery from the samples folder passed. Here is the output:

```
~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 630"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.0 / 9.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 4022 MBytes (4217110528 bytes)
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, ( 64) CUDA Cores/MP:     128 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1400 MHz (1.40 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             667 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 131072 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

However, when I try to build the other samples and run them, I get the following runtime API error 18. A window flashes and closes immediately.

```
./boxFilter Starting...

Loaded './data/lenaRGB.ppm', 1024 x 1024 pixels

Found 1 CUDA Capable device(s) supporting CUDA

Device 0: "GeForce GT 630"
  CUDA Runtime Version     :    9.0
  CUDA Compute Capability  :    2.1

Found CUDA Capable Device 0: "GeForce GT 630"
Setting active device to 0
boxFilter_kernel.cu(348) : CUDA Runtime API error 18: invalid texture reference.
```

And with other samples:

```
simpleGL (VBO) starting...

MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
```

How do I solve this? Is it a problem with the installation of drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GeForce GT630 have less than 64 SM Cores
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  **Default to use 64 Cores/SM**
Had the same problem with my 310 witch owns only 48 cores. With cuda 9.0 the compilation of the program runs fine but generates errors and the execution is not possible because your card doesn't owns 64 cores. You should go back to cuda 8.0 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive
and install it from a local installer so you don't go back to cuda 9.0 when you will upgrade your system... If you need cuda 9.0 you will have to buy a new nvidia card with a minimum of 64 cores/SM

Hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

Fermi support (`CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: 2.X`) was removed from CUDA 9: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#unsupported-features.

So you need to go back to CUDA 8.